# Implementing Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have implemented Retrofit to return some data from the service, but the size is 0, in getGamesData function it would not go inside the callback method.

I am not sure if the way i declared BASE_URL is right and the ApiInterface method GET.

OnResponse and OnFailure methods are not called at all.

Please suggest

URL that returns me data.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/abcd/gameData

which returns me a JSON like this.

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "currency" : "GBP",
    "data" : [
        {
            "name": "Game 1",
            "jackpot": 34000000,
            "date": "2015-01-25T20:20:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 2",
            "jackpot": 100000000,
            "date": "2015-02-16T08:40:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 3",
            "jackpot": 100000,
            "date": "2015-11-09T10:25:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 4",
            "jackpot": 45000000,
            "date": "2015-03-10T18:55:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 5",
            "jackpot": 60000000,
            "date": "2015-07-20T03:45:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 6",
            "jackpot": 95000000,
            "date": "2015-06-22T09:40:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 7",
            "jackpot": 100000000,
            "date": "2015-10-19T08:30:30+01:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "Game 8",
            "jackpot": 12000,
            "date": "2015-12-06T07:20:30+01:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/abcd/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public  static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit == null)
        {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface - Updated

```
   public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/gameData")
    Call<GamesWebOrbEntity> getGamesData();
}
```

ApiCalls - updated

```
public class ApiCalls implements IApiCalls{
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;
    private GamesWebOrbEntity gamesEntities;

    @Override
    public GamesWebOrbEntity getGamesData() {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<GamesWebOrbEntity> call = apiInterface.getGamesData();
        try{
            call.enqueue(new Callback<GamesWebOrbEntity>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GamesWebOrbEntity> call, Response<GamesWebOrbEntity> response) {
                    gamesEntities = response.body();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GamesWebOrbEntity> call, Throwable t) {
                    String test = "Failure";

                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return gamesEntities;
    }
}
```

IApiCalls - Updated

```
public interface IApiCalls {

    GamesWebOrbEntity getGamesData();
}
```

GamesWebOrbEntity _ UpdaTED

```
public class GamesWebOrbEntity {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private String response;
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<GameEntity> gameEntities;
}
```

GameEntity

```
public class GameEntity {
    private String name;
    private Integer jackpot;
    private Date date;
}
```

Using it

```
List<GamesWebOrbEntity> gamesEntity = apiCalls.getGamesData();
```

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data does not match your Java POJO. 
What you are receiving ist not a list of objects, but an object that contains, with the key `data`, a list of objects.

Your Java class(es) should probably look something this:

```
public class GamesWebOrbEntity {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private String response;
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Game>;
}
public class Game {
 // name
 // jackpot
 // date
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that I should use all the fields coming from the JSON, I was under the impression that we can omit the ones that we do not require. correct me if I am wrong please

Comment: No, it's not mandatory, you can omit any fields. 
But the general structure of you classes has to match that of the JSON data; e.g. when the JSON is an object, you need to de-serialize it to an object (not to a list of objects, as you are trying). 

Did you check your LogCat for any errors? Might also be helpful.

Comment: As suggested, I have made the changes but that returns 0 still, I do not have any errors.

Comment: Update your question to the changes you've made please.

Comment: I have updated my question with the changes suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("gameData")
    Call<GamesWebOrbEntity> getGamesData();
}
```

remove the "/"before gameData and,the server gives you an object, not a list

```
public class GamesWebOrbEntity {
    private String response;
    private String currency;
    private List<GameEntity> gameEntities;
}
```

and :

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                  addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

Comment: tried that but does not work still. just to mention, code does not get into the onResponse method, after call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GamesWebOrbEntity>>() {, it skipps out of try catch.

Comment: it's not a list but a single object, so remove List<> please

Comment: @BRDroid You do print the error in your catch block, what does it say?

Comment: @Ascorbin there is no error, it does not catch anything, it skips after call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GamesWebOrbEntity>>() {

Comment: @BRDroid So neither onResponse nor onFailure are called?

Comment: Hi Dany, it is not going inside the OnResponse nor the OnFailure methods.

Comment: I know, but in catch       
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        } ????

Comment: it does not execute the catch block, I put a breakpoint in it but does not execute.

Comment: @DanyPoplawec Hi you have edited your answer but could not figure out what changes you have made to it. Retrofit.Builder is already part of the code.

Comment: You're right, it's an error. Future answer is coming

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GamesWebOrbEntity {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("response")
    private String response;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Game>;


public String getResponse() {
return response;

public String getCurrency() {
return currency;
}

public List<Game> getData() {
return data;
}

}

public class Game {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("jackpot")
    private String jackpot;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public int getJackpot() {
return jackpot;
}


public String getDate() {
return date;
}
}
```